# Speaker not working after using HDMI

Tags: sound, laptop, hdmi, asus

So, I've tried to use my laptop (Asus GU501) to watch a movie on my TV through the HDMI cable, but Ubuntu 16.04 bugged (something related to graphics configuration; a dialog box with a black screen) during startup.

I restarted the system (by pressing the power button for 10s). When I turned it on again, the speakers were not working anymore; not even in Windows 10 or Arch. The Post Logo Animation (ROG logo) on laptop startup doesn't reproduce any sound fx as it normally does.

Alsa keeps showing the internal speakers as an output option, I can use the P2 output and lscpci -v shows the device.

Is there any chance that Ubuntu turned the speakers off? Or maybe something related to secureboot happened?

Please, help :<

```
0:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 3ec4 (rev 07)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1fd0
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 122
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00004000-00004fff
    Memory behind bridge: dc000000-dd0fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000b0000000-00000000c1ffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e9b (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    DeviceName: Second VGA
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1fd0
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 129
    Memory at db000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 70000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 5000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at dd310000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
    Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device

00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Gaussian Mixture Model
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Skylake Gaussian Mixture Model
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
    Memory at dd32c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device a379 (rev 10)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1fd0
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at dd32b000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
    Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device a36d (rev 10) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 201f
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 126
    Memory at dd300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device a36f (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 7270
    Flags: fast devsel
    Memory at dd322000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=8K]
    Memory at dd32a000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device a370 (rev 10)
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0034
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at dd31c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a368 (rev 10)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1fd0
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at a2400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a369 (rev 10)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1fd0
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at a2401000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device a360 (rev 10)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1fd0
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 137
    Memory at dd327000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device a353 (rev 10) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1fd0
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 127
    Memory at dd320000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Memory at dd326000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at 5090 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 5080 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 5060 [size=32]
    Memory at dd325000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a340 (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 123
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00006000-00006fff
    Memory behind bridge: a2000000-a21fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000a2200000-00000000a23fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1b.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a32c (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 124
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=3b, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00007000-00007fff
    Memory behind bridge: c4000000-da0fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000080000000-00000000a1ffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a330 (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 125
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=3c, subordinate=3c, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff
    Memory behind bridge: dd200000-dd2fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a30d (rev 10)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1fd0
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0

00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device a348 (rev 10)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 15be
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 153
    Memory at dd318000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at dd100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device a323 (rev 10)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1fd0
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 255
    Memory at dd324000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at efa0 [size=32]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a324 (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 7270
    Flags: fast devsel
    Memory at fe010000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1c20 (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    DeviceName: VGA
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 185e
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255
    Memory at dc000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at 4000 [disabled] [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at dd000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_390, nvidia_390_drm

3c:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Kingston Technologies Device 5008 (rev 01) (prog-if 02 [NVM Express])
    Subsystem: Kingston Technologies Device 5008
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at dd200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=8]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme
```

Comment: I have no idea, but doubt it. It's more likely in my opinion the power out caused a power spike, which fried a component or poor line/trace on a board which is no longer letting electricity through.

Comment: I don't think it is the case, but is there any way to test it?

Comment: Testing it would involved entering UEFI/BIOS, or using the diagnostics for your system.  I've seen a machine before that had its cmos info corrupted because of a forced-shutdown, a reset of it's values (back to defaults) and it was good to go for awhile (turns out its battery was poor and a few months later was replaced...)  But this is all machine-specific & off-topic here, as unrelated to Ubuntu.

Comment: I can't find anything related to the speakers in my BIOS. I can just turn on/off the Post Logo sound fx (it is currently enabled). I've tried to reinstall the driver through Ubuntu and Windows, and now it cannot even use HDMI as an audio output. I have a strong intuition that it is driver related...